# Android build fails when build with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, manifest, unity-game-engine

I got a strange problem lately with my eclipse build. When building my app via Unity everything works fine and the build runs ok, but I need to get it working with eclipse as I have some plugins I want to use.

I'm using the same Manifest.xml as generated by Unity only changing the package name and the name of the activity as stated in the docs. Has someone a hint what could be the problem?

Logcat throws out:

```
03-27 15:08:39.632: W/dalvikvm(5289): Unable to resolve superclass of Lde/indiegames/hyperjump/HyperJumpActivity; (34)
03-27 15:08:39.632: W/dalvikvm(5289): Link of class 'Lde/indiegames/hyperjump/HyperJumpActivity;' failed
03-27 15:08:39.632: D/AndroidRuntime(5289): Shutting down VM
03-27 15:08:39.632: W/dalvikvm(5289): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.indiegames.hyperjump/de.indiegames.hyperjump.HyperJumpActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.indiegames.hyperjump.HyperJumpActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/de.indiegames.hyperjump-2/pkg.apk]
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.indiegames.hyperjump.HyperJumpActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/de.indiegames.hyperjump-2/pkg.apk]
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
03-27 15:08:39.679: E/AndroidRuntime(5289):     ... 11 more
03-27 15:08:39.687: W/ActivityManager(104):   Force finishing activity de.indiegames.hyperjump/.HyperJumpActivity
03-27 15:08:40.202: W/ActivityManager(104): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{405479b8 de.indiegames.hyperjump/.HyperJumpActivity}
```

My HyperJump.java class

```
package de.indiegames.hyperjump;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class HyperJumpActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate instance");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume called..");

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

My Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="de.indiegames.hyperjump" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
  <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="true" />

  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <!-- ACTIVITIES -->
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".HyperJumpActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.IntroFlow" android:label="IntroFlow" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.api.ui.Dashboard" android:label="Dashboard" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.Settings" android:label="Settings" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.NativeBrowser" android:label="NativeBrowser" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.CatalogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="make.me.unique.please" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Tapjoy -->
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJCOffersWebView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyFeaturedAppWebView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyVideoView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <!-- SERVICES AND RECEIVERS -->
    <service android:name="com.prime31.billing.BillingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.prime31.billing.BillingReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Any hint would be helpful!

Comment: For whatever reason your HyperActivity superclass cannot be found. Can you clean your build and then rebuild to be sure it's in the pkg that gets uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just upgrade to SDK 17?
http://sastraxi.com/the-solution-to-sdk-17-verifyerrors-and-third-party-jars/

Comment: Yeha. You saved my day! I have to include an external lib for the unity player and this lib was not checked. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

It says it can't resolve the superclass, UnityPlayerActivity. I've never used Unity, so I don't know how you include their code library; maybe you need to do something special to include the Unity classes.